# find max sum in array with fixed number of turns and initial position

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

This is a problem i had in a test, and i didn't know how to answer it, so i forward this to you guys:

Find a polynomial time algorithm this problem:
You get an array of N positive integers (with fixed range) , a starting position (number between 0 to N-1),and a fixed number of turns.
In each turn, one can decide if to take the array[where he stand on now] and add it to a sum (and then you need to remember that this cell is empty), or to skip , and go left or right.

You need to find the maximum sum we can get.
for example:

```
array = {70,3,100}  
STARTING_POSITION = 2  
TURNS = 4
```

the output : `170`

turn 1 - take the 100 , turn 2 - move left, turn 3 - move left,turn 4 - take the 70.

I thought about dynamic programming but i didn't know to deal with the cells i already took - this influence on the whole table for this approach.

Comment: Why is dealing with cells you already took a problem? Just make a copy of the array, and you can erase cells in that at will.

Comment: This is a "homework" question I'm actually intrigued to see.

Comment: I don't think this ia a homework question. It seems an ACM-ICPC problem.